# Should we use the ETL tag narrowly or broadly?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I retagged [this (closed) question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28517/syntax-error-from-copy-into-postgresql) with [etl](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etl) assuming the tag should cover *all* (non-SQL) aspects of getting all sorts of data into an RDBMS.

There is also [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25355/how-to-import-sybase-db-file-into-sql-server-database)—the only one tagged [data-import](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-import) which I suggest we retag [etl](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etl). However perhaps I'm interpreting ETL too broadly and we should restrict to the specialised sense of Data Warehousing?

Comment: I only know that when I hear or use the word ETL, I mean the narrower sense.  This may be my fault, of course :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can certainly use an ETL tool to populate something that isn't a data warehouse - for example I'm currently working on a process that de-duplicates data and populates a CRM system.  I'd call it an ETL process.  Looks like a duck, quacks like a duck.

However in the case of the question that the OP is referring to, the task the poster seems to be trying to achieve might be better described as [data-migration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-migration) than [etl](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etl).

I'd say [etl](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etl) belongs on processing with significant 'E' and 'T' (extraction and transformation) components.  ETL is traditionally associated with data warehousing and the term was coined in that context.  However, populating data warehouse systems is a long way from being he only application for ETL processes.